# How do I create a executable with a make file in c

Tags: makefile

I am using a `Makefile` to create an executable file, so that when I run the executable I just write `./ft_ls`, but get this error, below it is the code of my Makefile.

> "ar: ft_ls: Inappropriate file type or format"

But when I create a library and add my `main.c` file and gcc, it runs `file.so`. How do I create an executable from the below Makefile?

```
14 NAME = ft_ls
 15
 16 SRCS =  main.c\
 17         ft_perm.c\
 18         ft_group.c\
 19         count.c\
 20         ls_l.c\
 21         ls.c\
 22         ls_a.c\
 23         ls_rr.c\
 24         ls_r.c\
 25         ls_r_m.c\
 26         multi_args_l.c\
 27         ft_anigma.c\
 28         ls_g.c\
 29         ft_printf/ft_printf.c\
 30         ft_printf/precision.c ft_printf/mask_unicode.c ft_printf/width.c ft_printf/null_char.c ft_printf/wstr_precision.c\
 31         ft_printf/flags/flags.c ft_printf/flags/type_flags.c ft_printf/flags/checking_for.c ft_printf/n_func.c\
 32         ft_printf/conv/applying.c ft_printf/conv/conversion.c ft_printf/conv/zero_conv.c\
 33         ft_printf/alloc/ft_alloc.c ft_printf/alloc/to_str.c ft_printf/libft/ft_atoi.c ft_printf/alloc/ft_del_str.c\
 34         ft_printf/libft/ft_strncpy.c ft_printf/libft/ft_strcmp.c libft/ft_strncmp.c ft_printf/libft/ft_putstr.c ft_printf/color_part_two.c \
 35         ft_printf/libft/ft_strcpy.c ft_printf/libft/ft_strlen.c ft_printf/libft/ft_strdup.c \
 36         ft_printf/test/h_test.c ft_printf/test/jz_test.c ft_printf/test/l_test.c ft_printf/test/basic_test.c \
 37         ft_printf/itoa/ft_itoa_ll.c ft_printf/itoa/reverse.c ft_printf/libft/ft_strwdup.c ft_printf/color.c \
 38
 39 OB =    main.o \
 40         ft_perm.o\
 41         ft_group.o\
 42         count.o\
 43         ls_l.o\
 44         ls.o\
 45         ls_a.o\
 46         ls_rr.o\
 47         ls_r.o\
 48         ls_r_m.o\
 49         multi_args_l.o\
 50         ft_anigma.o\
 51         ls_g.o\
 52         ft_printf.o\
 53         type_flags.o applying.o basic_test.o checking_for.o conversion.o \
 54         flags.o ft_alloc.o ft_atoi.o mask_unicode.o n_func.o\
 55         ft_printf.o ft_strcmp.o ft_strcpy.o to_str.o wstr_precision.o\
 56         ft_strdup.o ft_strlen.o ft_strncpy.o h_test.o jz_test.o l_test.o precision.o \
 57         reverse.o width.o ft_itoa_ll.o null_char.o zero_conv.o ft_strwdup.o color.o \
 58         ft_putstr.o color_part_two.o ft_del_str.o ft_strncmp.o\
 59
 60 FLAGS = -Werror -Wall -Wextra
 61
 62 $(NAME):
 63     gcc  $(FLAGS) $(SRCS)  -o $(NAME)
 64
 65 all:    $(NAME)
 66
 67 clean:
 68     rm -f $(OB)
 69
 70 fclean: clean
 71     rm -f $(NAME)
 72
 73 re:     fclean all
```

Comment: remove `-c` from your `gcc` line, and remove the `ar` line.  FWIW, `-c` means "stop after compiling, producing object files", vs. the default behavior of trying to link all of the compiled code into an executable.  The `ar` command is literally short for "archive"...because a static library (.a) is really just a slightly special tar archive of object files.

Comment: i tried doing that, but this what i get undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ft_printf", referenced from:
      _main_malti in main-4da9d1.o
      _main in main-4da9d1.o
  "_ft_strcmp", referenced from:
      _main_malti in main-4da9d1.o
      _main in main-4da9d1.o
  "_ls", referenced from:
      _main in main-4da9d1.o

Comment: Okay, that's the real issue; if that implies you're working on a Mac (so as to have universal binaries) that would be a good tag to add to the problem.  Is x86_64 the platform you're developing on?  Are you setting any architecture flags in CFLAGs? (e.g., -m32 or -m64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 66 $(NAME):
 67     gcc -c $(FLAGS) -o ft_ls $(MAIN) $(OBJ)
 68     ar rc $(NAME) $(OB)
```

In the above snippet, you have a target $(NAME) [= ft_ls] without any dependencies and two commands, which are trying to create an executable and a library. Additionally you define a variable called OB but refer to a variable called OBJ. I suspect that you should only be creating an executable, like this

```
$(NAME): $(MAIN) $(OB)
    gcc $(FLAGS) -o ft_ls $(MAIN) $(OB)
```

If you are using GNU make then you can use $@ for the target and $^ for the dependencies (this makes your Makefile easier to maintain), like this

```
$(NAME): $(MAIN) $(OB)
    gcc $(FLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

It's not clear how your object files get compiled. If you just have a bunch of .c files and require some .o files then it's probably the `suffix rule` that gets used (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html)), so you would need something like

```
.c.o:
        $(CC) -c $(FLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Ha! I didn't even notice `OBJ` was typoed.  The OP's link error (clarified in the comments) will come because `OBJ`  expands to a blank string; the correct answer needs to either rename the `OB` list to `OBJ` or change the references to properly use `OB` (or an automatic make variable as this answer does)

Comment: thank you all for your assistance, it works file now. the code is above